# My docker container can't see new files in its volume after composing it

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose

I have a Nextjs app with a few other images in my docker-compose file with a bind volume on my ubuntu VPM

The problem is that I can't see any new files that I upload to the website after composing it, I can only see the ones that were in **/root/docker/public** at the composing time. When I upload new files, they appear on the virtual machine in **/root/docker/public** and in the container itself (I checked via **docker exec -it NAME sh** command) but the website just can't see them. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is my **docker-compose.yaml**:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  nextjs:
    image: olegvegan/oochoo
    container_name: nextjs
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /root/docker/public
        target: /oochooapp/public
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    container_name: database
    command:
      [
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      ]
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql8db:/var/lib/mysql
  frontend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: staticfloat/nginx-certbot
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    environment:
      CERTBOT_EMAIL: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
      - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

volumes:
  letsencrypt:
  mysql8db:
```

Nextjs image **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:16.19.1-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /oochooapp
RUN npm install --global pm2

COPY . .
RUN npm install --omit=dev
RUN npm run build
ENV NODE_ENV production
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

Before trying **bind mound** I think I had **volume mount**, but It doesn't seem to change anything. The website can't see new files that I upload

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with your compose file. This might rather be an issue with the app itself. Indeed, it may build an internal list of available files at startup and does not refresh it upon requests.

Comment: Does restarting the container make your changes visible?  Also, PM2 has a "watch" configuration which is useful for local development, https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/, if that was your expectation.

Comment: Yes, when I update some code and files and re-compose it, I can see the changes. But all the new uploads are invisible to the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it's just how Next.js works

> Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be
> served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets

Comment: What was your solution though?